# Getting frequent Error: no open connections and Error: connection closed during heavy concurrent load

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We are facing this issue for long and in production can't afford this type of crashes. We have used high-end EC2 Instances to process the heavy workload. This type of error only occur under the heavy workload, otherwise, it works fine.

I have also checked MongoDB CPU, RAM and query load during the crash but everything was normal at that time. The only issue which we have faced was in node server which was restarted with below error of MongoDB.

**Instance 1: Node Server**

- c5.4xlarge: 16 CPU and 32 GB RAM with SSD storage
- Node version: 6.11
- MongoDB NPM Version: 1.4.28
- CPU Utilization is 30-40 % in normal condition with 8 Socket servers
- CPU Utilization is 70-80 % during the crash with 8 Socket servers

**Instance 2: Standalone MongoDB Server**

- r4.2xlarge: 8 CPU and 61 GB RAM with SSD storage
- MongoDB Version: 3.2.20
- CPU Utilization average 300% out of 800% and remain the same during
  crash also.

**Error logs from node socket server:**

```
DB Error V2RP : Error: connection closed
at .<anonymous> (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:617:45)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at emit (events.js:185:7)
at .<anonymous> (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:165:15)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at emit (events.js:191:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:550:12)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at CallbackStore.<anonymous> (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9)
at CallbackStore.g (events.js:292:16)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: failed to connect to [xxx.xx.x.xxx:27017]
at .<anonymous> (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:555:25)
at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
at emit (events.js:194:7)
at .<anonymous> (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:150:15)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at emit (events.js:191:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:343:10)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at CallbackStore.<anonymous> (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9)
at CallbackStore.g (events.js:292:16)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error V2RP : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at rec (/home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1446:144)
at /home/game/classes/dashboard.class.js:1457:41
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:169:22
at commandHandler (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:693:48)
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
DB Error MP pit : Error: no open connections
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:23)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
at Cursor.nextObject (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:749:13)
at Cursor.toArray (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:168:10)
at /home/game/classes/profile.class.js:508:144
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/commands.js:54:20
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1170:22
at /home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
at __executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1719:14)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/home/game/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1881:7)
```

Comment: I have also added {auto_reconnect: true} in the node to resolve [Error: no open connections]  . But still getting same error.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How do you open connection to the MongoDB server? Do you open a connection for each db query or is there a single connection that is shared all across the app?